Placing individual images in Quiz questions react native
I'm still having a problem with this...  here is the code question example on my .js data file:
Now I've added the whole block of code, the part that I am mostly interested in..  I hope this helps:
export default data = [
  {
    question: "1. How would you say 'Cherry' in Italian?   ", 
    image: require('../../assets/images/cartoon_cherry.png'),
    options: ["Mela", "Ciliegia", "Fragola"],
    correct_option: "Ciliegia"
  },
  {
    question: "2. How would you say 'Strawberry' in Italian?",
    image: require('../../assets/images/strawberry.png'),    
    options: ["Mela", "Ciliegia", "Fragola"],
    correct_option: "Fragola"
  },
  ...
]

on my .jsx code:
 const renderQuestion = () => {
        const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height;
        const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width;
        const question = data[0];
          
     return (
            <View style={{
                marginVertical: '5%',
                width: windowWidth < 500 ? '100%' : '60%',
                height: windowHeight > 500 ? '40%' : '90%'
    }}>
           {/* This is the question counter: */ }
                <View style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'flex-end',
                    marginBottom: '5%'
                }}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 15, opacity: 0.6, marginRight: 2}}>{currentQuestionIndex+1}</Text>
                    <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 15, opacity: 0.6}}>/ {allQuestions.length}</Text>

                </View>

                 {/* This is the question below: */ }
                
                 <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 22, paddingTop: '-50%'}}>
                    {allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]?.question} </Text>
                        
                           <View>
                         <Image source={question.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
                        </View>   
              </View>
        )
}
This is the block of code I was working with....  I hope this will help!!!!

Now my problem is that the cherries come out on every question.  If I change the array to `const question = data[1]` as an example, then the strawberry will come out on every question. If I place it like an array: `const question = data[0, 1, 2]` then  the third image will display on every question. So how can I fix this?


Are you trying to map the data array to JSX somewhere? You are not showing complete code. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and clarify what you are trying to accomplish and what the issue is in better detail. Try to take the full [tour] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Hello Drew, I'm sorry, i'm new to Stack Overflow.  I've read your advice and I really thank you.  Now i've re-sent the block of code, the part that i'm mostly interested in, I hope this was sufficient.  I thought that I had to try to map the data array in my JSX, but then again, I don' know if that was correct.  So i'm hoping on some good advice here, since I am also new to React Native.  I do quizzes in JavaScript with images, but can't seem to get RN straight when it comes to images...

Hello Drew, I'm sorry, i'm new to Stack Overflow.  I've read your advice and I really thank you.  Now i've re-sent the block of code, the part that i'm mostly interested in, I hope this was sufficient.  I thought that I had to try to map the data array in my JSX, but then again, I don' know if that was correct.  So i'm hoping on some good advice here, since I am also new to React Native.  I do quizzes in JavaScript with images, but can't seem to get RN straight when it comes to images...

If you want to display corresponding image for each question you can try to pass the question index or essential data to renderQuestion component as below:
const renderQuestion = ({index}) => {        
  const question = data[index];

  return (
    // ...
                        
    <View>
      <Image source={question.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
    </View>   
)}

// USAGE:
const renderQuestions = () => {        
  return (<>
    {
      data.map((question,index) => <renderQuestion index={index} />)
    }
    </>
)}

Another and my preferred usage:
const renderQuestion = ({ image, question }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 22, paddingTop: "-50%" }}>
        {question}
      </Text>

      <View>
        <Image source={image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

// USAGE:
const renderQuestions = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((question, index) => (
        <renderQuestion image={question.image} index={question.index} />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

If I can see your whole code it would be easier to solve the problem.

Hi Vusal, ok, this is the block of code I was working with:

@Susy you can use the implementations listed in my answer. I didn't understand what the problem is. Because, your code works properly. If you map the data my second implementation is good for you.

It gives me "image" undefined.....  I tried defining the image, but i'm probably making a mistake.  Can u tell me how u would define "image"?

Of course. You can use it as question.image. Take a look at the second example.

Hi Vusal!!!  This puts the images on the questions, but I now have all images on each question....  but I must say, very impressive for a very young man to have such knowledge!!!  Do u know what I can do from here?

Hi @Susy! Thanks. My code targets to display image for corresponding question. Can you explain what you are trying to do a little bit detailed?

Hello again Vusal!!!  In fact, your code does display the images, all of them, and I think that maybe I am getting close to the solution, with your help of course, but all the images display on only the first question.  So, I think that maybe something should change on the .js file.  Maybe the problem is there.  You see the .js example I wrote above?  export default data = [ {question: 1. xxx xxxx xxxx, image:  xxxxx xxx, options: xxxxxxxxx

Hello again Vusal!!!  In fact, your code does display the images, all of them, and I think that maybe I am getting close to the solution, with your help of course, but all the images display on only the first question.  So, I think that maybe something should change on the .js file.  Maybe the problem is there.  You see the .js example I wrote above?  export default data = [ {question: 1. xxx xxxx xxxx, image:  xxxxx xxx, options: xxxxxxxxx, correct_option: xxxxxxx,  maybe i should try with a "key" instead.  What do you think?  I will re-send the code I wrote, which is the one you said to use:

<Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 22, paddingTop: '-50%'}}>
{allQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]?.question} 
<>
{data.map((question, index) => (
<Image source={question.image} index={question.index} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
    ))}
    </>

